# Taking github repo public causes problems with Dist::Zilla

Tags: perl, github, dist-zilla

I have a module, built with `Dist::Zilla`. I have `Dist::Zilla` set up to automatically push changes out to my GitHub repo. Works great when the repo is private.

However, as soon as I make the repo public, I start getting errors during the build process. Specifically, these lines in the `dist.ini`

```
[Bugtracker]
web = http://github.com/myaccount/%s/issues
```

If I comment out these lines, it works. With these lines left in, I get an error:

```
Duplication of element resources.bugtracker.web at /Users/me/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.24.1/lib/site_perl/5.24.4/Dist/Zilla.pm line 595.
```

OK, so fine, I comment out the lines. However, another problem crops up. The version number of my builds no longer autoincrements and is stuck at the same number every time I try to release a build.

Is there some configuration setting I need to change with Dist::Zilla so it will play nice with public github repos? Here is the full dist.ini file:

```
name    = Module-Test
author  = me
license = Perl_5
copyright_holder = Me
copyright_year   = 2018

[Repository]
;[Bugtracker]
;web = http://github.com/sdondley/%s/issues
[Git::NextVersion]
[GitHub::Meta]
[PodVersion]
[PkgVersion]
[NextRelease]
[Run::AfterRelease]
run = mv Changes tmp && cp %n-%v/Changes Changes
[InstallGuide]

[PodWeaver]
[ReadmeAnyFromPod]
type = markdown
location = root
phase = release

[Git::Check]
[Git::Commit]
allow_dirty = README.mkdn
allow_dirty = Changes
allow_dirty = INSTALL
[Git::Tag]
[Git::Push]
[Run::AfterRelease / MyAppAfter]
run = mv tmp/Changes Changes

[GatherDir]
[AutoPrereqs]
[PruneCruft]
[PruneFiles]
filename = weaver.ini
filename = README.mkdn
filename = dist.ini
filename = .gitignore
[ManifestSkip]
[MetaYAML]
[License]
[Readme]
[ExtraTests]
[ExecDir]
[ShareDir]
[MakeMaker]
[Manifest]
[TestRelease]
[FakeRelease]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `[Bugtracker]` entry leads to duplication because you are also setting the bugtracker through `[GitHub::Meta]`. Choose one or the other.

As for version number management, note that `[Git::NextVersion]` is based on your git tags. Make sure that these tags are present in your local repository and have the correct format. That plugin uses a command line invocation similar to this to obtain all tags:

```sh
git rev-list --simplify-by-decoration --pretty=%d HEAD | grep -oE 'tag: [^,)\s]+'
```

Public GitHub repos should not be a problem for Dist::Zilla – this is exactly the setup most dzil distros use anyway. But interactions between multiple plugins can lead to hard to track down bugs, especially since the order of plugins is important. It can help to organize your plugins by the phase in which they run, and to test whether the problem persists after removing optional plugins. It also tends to be better to start with a simple `dist.ini` and add plugins as pain points in your development process become apparent.